# inequation of sinuses of triangle's angles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be inner angels of a triangle. Prove that the follwoing inequation is fulfilled:
$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma \ge \sin^3\alpha+\sin^3\beta+\sin^3\gamma$

Comment: i think the inequality sign must be reversed

Comment: Can You prove that the revesed inequation is fulfilled then? :)

Comment: yes i can prove this

Comment: I'd be grateful if You showed me the proof.

Comment: ok i will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will prove that
$$\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)+\sin(\gamma)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\le \sin(\alpha)^3+\sin(\beta)^3+\sin(\gamma)^3$$
we use that
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{a}{2R}$$ etc and $$A=\frac{abc}{4R}$$ and $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
plugging this in the given inequality we have to prove that
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+abc-\frac{(abc)^2(a+b+c)}{4s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\geq 0$$ with $$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$ this is equivalent to
$${\frac {{a}^{6}-{a}^{5}b-{a}^{5}c-{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+3\,{a}^{4}bc-{a}^{4}{
c}^{2}+2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}-2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}c-2\,{a}^{3}b{c}^{2}+2\,{a}^
{3}{c}^{3}-{a}^{2}{b}^{4}-2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}c+6\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-
2\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{3}-{a}^{2}{c}^{4}-a{b}^{5}+3\,a{b}^{4}c-2\,a{b}^{3}{c}
^{2}-2\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{3}+3\,ab{c}^{4}-a{c}^{5}+{b}^{6}-{b}^{5}c-{b}^{4}
{c}^{2}+2\,{b}^{3}{c}^{3}-{b}^{2}{c}^{4}-b{c}^{5}+{c}^{6}}{ \left( a+b
-c \right)  \left( a-b+c \right)  \left( a-b-c \right) }}
\le 0$$
now using the Ravi-substitution:
$$a=y+z,b=x+z,c=x+y$$
and we get after simplification:
$${\frac { \left( x-z \right) ^{2} \left( x+y \right) ^{2}}{-2\,z+x-y}}\le0$$
which is true.

Comment: since $$.2z+x-y=-2a+c$$  the inequality above is only fulfilled if $$-2a+c<0$$ is hold

Comment: This solution is crazy!